# discord.py Can I get a user ID using just the user's name?

Tags: discord.py

discord.py, Can I get a user ID using just the user's name?

I want to know the syntax

utils.find? MemberConverter?

discord.Guild.get_member_named?

Comment: Be more specific. Try to show what you have done till now.

Comment: This is complicated because you ain't got the members in your cache, so you can't use discord.utils.find to find them by name. The only option would be to get the member by a message, reaction or any action he does or by his ID. (The problem with the cache isn't only your problem, I don't know any person that got the members in cache)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a guild object then you can

```py
member = discord.utils.get(guild.members, name="name")
member_id = member.id
```

Comment: Can I replace this code with the code below?

Comment: member = discord.utils.get(self.bot.guilds.members, name="name")
member_id = member.id